# tf.print in Keras call function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want to print a tensor to a file from a call function of a layer in Keras (an instance of the class Layer). Now, I use the tf.print function in the following way

```
myTensor = ...
print_op = tf.print("tensor: ", myTensor, summarize=-1, output_stream=‘file:///...’)
with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
    nextTensor = myTensor * ...
```

The statement works and prints the values of the tensor to the external file whenever I call “model.fit(...)” but does not print anything (and no error message) when I call “model.predict(...)” or “model.evaluate()”. Does anyone know why?